# Run cpp file without compiling

Tags: gcc, g++, mingw-w64

How to directly run a c++ file present in read-only storage like CD-drive without making executable files using g++? There must be some arguments for that to work.

Comment: You could create a script to compile, run, then delete the binary to somewhat obtain this flow? Otherwise I don't think what you're looking for is possible. Is there a reason for wanting to do this?

Comment: In order to run a C++ program, you need a C++ implementation. This is a given. `g++` is one C++ implementation. It works by making executable files. There are several other mainstream implementations that all work much the same way. You may want to ask yourself whether an implementation that works *without making executable files* is indeed a hard requirement. Perhaps this is your interpretation of the real requirement that says something else entirely? Once you are sure that this is indeed a requirement, you may start looking for a *C++ interpreter* (none of those are mainstream).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The process of a C/C++ program when you make one till you run it:

1. You write the program's source code.
2. The compiler comes in here and compiles the source code to object files.
   Note: Remember that the program cannot be executed at this stage. It's only an object file. You'd know this if you have worked on bigger size programs, but if you haven't here is how it works. Remember using those header files in your programs? These header files just tell the compiler that there are some things that are not defined in your program. They are somewhere else. So your compile compiles the program to the object file leaving out things that have a prototype (which is in the header files).
3. This is a very important point. Here a program called 'linker' comes into play. What linker does is to take all the object files created by compiler and combines them into one. Say for example your compiler created a single object file. Now, you're using math library or anything from standard library. The compiler-linker package (often called only compiler) comes with object files for these standard library definitions. So, linker takes your object file and combines it with other object files from the package and then converts it to an executable file. This is the file that you can run. Nothing else is runnable directly.

To run source code the process is explained already, we have to use the g++. Now

What I understand from your question is that you want to know if a program can be run once it's compiled and linked properly (hence an executable has been generated). Answer to that would be yes.

Alternatively, may sound strange, there is an interpreter I know called Cling that can be of use to bypass the compilation of C++ program.
After all C++ is generally seen as a compiled language. However, any programming language can be implemented as a compiler or as an interpreter and Cling happens to be an interactive C++ interpreter based on LLVM and Clang.
Take a thorough look at [this](https://solarianprogrammer.com/2012/08/14/cling-cpp-11-interpreter/)